# Mifare classic 1k and NFC communication protocol

Tags: protocols, nfc, mifare

which protocol is used (other than NDEF protocol) for communication between Mifare classic 1k and nfc enabled mobile, when we raed or write indvisual blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NDEF is not a communication protocol, but the message content description:

"*...The NDEF specification defines a message encapsulation format to
exchange information... NDEF is a lightweight, binary message format that can be used to encapsulate one or more application-defined payloads of arbitrary type and size into a single message construct. Each payload is described by a type, a length, and an optional identifier.
Type identifiers may be URIs, MIME media types, or NFC-specific types...*"

The protocol to read/write Mifare sectors is a proprietary see e.g. here: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S503x.pdf

BR
STeN

Comment: PDF link is broken :(